# Rails 5: Accept terms of service with omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently trying to integrate the acceptance of terms for omniauth facebook.

I have a field `:terms_of_service`, but this doesn't fire when I click on the facebook button.

I tried with `validates_acceptance_of :terms_of_service` but this didn't work.

For my "standard" registration I used `<%= f.check_box :terms_of_service, required: true %>`

can I achieve something similar with facebook?

I thought using `before_action :terms_of_service, only: [:facebook]`, but couldn't figure out how to check if the checkbox is valid

My User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :omniauthable

  validates :fullname, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4 }
  validates_acceptance_of :terms_of_service

  has_many :services
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :articles
  has_many :lists
  has_one  :first_reservation, -> { order('created_at ASC')}, class_name: "Reservation"

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    user = User.where(email: auth.info.email).first

    if user
      return user
    else
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.fullname = auth.info.name
      user.image = auth.info.image
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.skip_confirmation!
    end
  end
end
end
```